# Web Form Builder Tutorial

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I would like to have a go at building a 'Wufoo' type form builder. I have seen a few, and understand the logic behind creating it with the aid of javascript. However saving those form preferences for a returning user seems more complex for me, I was wondering if anywone has seen any examples/turorials of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an experimental [JSON-based form generator](http://preview.moveable.com/JM/jameslab/jsonform/). You describe your form using JSON and a bit of JavaScript code generates the form. You could then serialize and store the form data in a database (even as a text blob if you're lazy), then re-load it on the client and generate the form.

You're welcome to [the code](http://preview.moveable.com/JM/jameslab/jsonform/) if it gives you any ideas. It's all there in the page source.

Answer (score 1):

[ExtJS is building a tool](http://www.extjs.com/blog/2009/10/08/ext-js-designer-preview/) to create forms.  The prototypes look pretty nice, but they have not released the tool yet.